# Electron printToPDF page break in middle of text

Tags: pdf-generation, electron

I have an electron project that is generating a pdf using the built in *webContents.printToPDF()* function.

```
mainWindow.webContents.printToPDF({}, function(error, data) {
    if(error) throw error;
    fs.writeFile(arg, data, function(error) {
        if(error) throw error;
    });
});
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when I am printing a table that spans multiple pages the page breaks do not occur around elements, instead cut words in half, as in the example attached below.

[image]

I am using electron-prebuilt 0.35.2 for this project, and the program is being run on a windows 7 computer. I did not find a related issue when I search through [electron's github issues](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using [PhotonKit](http://photonkit.com/) as my CSS framework. This framework uses a flexbox for layout.

After replacing PhotonKit with Bootstrap the issue with the text breaking in between table cells was resolved. I believe that this was directly caused by chromium not dealing with the flexbox layout for printing properly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post this as a comment because I don't have the necessary reputation.

This seems to be a problem with Chromium and not with Electron. You can try to use `page-break-inside: avoid;`, either for `tr` or for `div`s within the table cells. I haven't tested this though.

You could also try to set `display: block;` for `tr`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I tried all three of the solutions you mentioned and none of them worked.

I think that I am going to try and compute the height of the table as I am adding rows to the table and create manual splits.